# Visual Studio code : terminated with error code 2

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

An error message is occurring repeatedly each time I attempt to use "Visual Studio Code". The terminal emulator that is integrated with VS Code is displaying the following error message:

**`C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`**
       
**`Terminated with exit code: 2.`**

I would like to know how I could resolve this issue, in a way where the error will no longer occur while I am using VS Code.

Comment: Did my answer solved your problem? You can consider accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:/WINDOWS/System32/cmd.exe"
```

to `settings.json`

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson

Comment: The direct link to the `settings.json` tutorial/explanation (so you don't have to scroll through the page) is [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson)

Comment: direct link edited.